# Vigenere cipher with full ASCII table

Tags: encryption, vigenere

I have an assignment in which I have to decrypt a text file encrypted with the Vigenere cipher. However, the alphabet used is the entire ASCII table (256 different characters), and I haven't found any material on how to deduce the key for this alphabet (as all material I've found assumes only a limited alphabet is used). Does anybody know how I should approach this problem? An explanation of good algorithms would be appreciated.

Comment: ASCII has only 128 characters. So, you should ask again about the input file encoding. (Perhaps it's Windows-1252, which has 251 characters. Perhaps it's something else.)

Comment: What problems have you encountered, exactly? The decryption procedure is exactly the same as for a traditional Vigenère cipher, except you are using an alphabet of 256 characters instead of 26.

Comment: @TomBlodget The course assignment page reads "Alphabet: ASCII table, all of 256 symbols", and the previous assignment used the full table as well.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage The problem is that we have to crack the encrypted file (with only the hint that the decrypted file should mention our name in the second line), meaning we have to figure out the key on our own. I know that it's possible to figure out the key by checking the frequencies of each possible Caesar shift (as explained [here](http://ibmathsresources.com/2014/05/31/crypto-analysis-to-crack-vigenere-ciphers/)), but I'm not sure if it works as well for encrypted messages using the whole ASCII table.

Comment: It is incorrect to say that ASCII has 256 symbols. Hopefully, they just got the name wrong but did provide the table they mean because there are many with about 256 characters. If you are expected to write a program in a particular language with a particular compiler for a particular OS with a particular default language, then maybe you all are implicitly agreeing to use the default character set and it could be possible to do so without knowing what it is. However, as I said, Windows-1252 has 251 characters so ciphertext that doesn't respect that should be treated as bytes and not text.

Comment: @MarkusM. As I said, you can use exactly the same procedure. You've even been given a crib, which makes things easier. I suggest you just get on with it and start writing some code. Come back if you have any specific difficulties.

Comment: @TomBlodget I know I am stirring an old question, but I think he meant this ASCII table with 256 symbols: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: @Kaitlyn As that page explains, it is not an ASCII table. It is a table for one particular "Extended ASCII" character set (and its one encoding). But, since there are so many, the term is hardly ever precise enough. At least that page does identify which character set it describes, even if it is in the fine print.

Comment: My bad. Thought it was as it proclaimed at the top of the page "ASCII Code - The extended ASCII table".